# How to set text in the center of the container in Flutter when trying to reduce container size?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-text, flutter-container

when text container size decrease with font size that time the text not set in center. it is gone below size of container how to solve it.

```
  Container(
              height: height,
              width: width,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              decoration: _isSelected
                  ? BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                border: Border.all(
                  width: 2,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              )
                  : null,

              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  _displayText.isEmpty ? 'Enter Text' : _displayText,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: fontSize,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

[image: this is image of output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the FittedBox widget to automatically scale the text to fit within the container while keeping it centred.

```
Container(
  height: height,
  width: width,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  decoration: _isSelected
      ? BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          border: Border.all(
            width: 2,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        )
      : null,
  child: FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.scaleDown, // Scale down the text to fit within the container
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text(
      _displayText.isEmpty ? 'Enter Text' : _displayText,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: fontSize,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the help of `Center()` like below:

```
Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          decoration: _isSelected
              ? BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            border: Border.all(
              width: 2,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          )
              : null,

          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              _displayText.isEmpty ? 'Enter Text' : _displayText,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
              maxLines: 1,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: fontSize,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: it is also not work same output show

Comment: Have you tried with giving Padding all (4) to container without mentioning height and width of the container and providing some constraints like: constraints: const BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: 200,
      ),

Comment: initially i have to given height 30 and width 95 according to "Enter Text" word.